# Gram–Schmidt vs Modified Gram–Schmidt vs Stable Gram–Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, gram-schmidt

I'm trying to understand what is the different between this 3 process, and till now what I understood is:

1. Modify process add $r_{ij}=u^T_jw_i$ and $r_{jj}=\sqrt{\|{w_j}\|^2-\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} r^2_{ji}}$ for $QR$ decomposition
2. Stable change the order of the steps $w_j\leftarrow w_j-(u^T_iw_j)u_i$

I found one nice [source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-335j-introduction-to-numerical-methods-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT18_335JF10_lec10a_hand.pdf) but not sure if they don't confused between Modify and Stable. Any explanation or correction are welcome

Comment: any explanation why downvote?

Comment: I suggest that you fix your misspellings, write grammatically correct and complete sentences and study the guide offered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)